# Using File class to write binary files in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, file-io, binaryfiles

I am trying to write a simple application that monitors the COM port and writes the incoming binary data to a file. So, I gathered a **File** class is provided, but looking at its methods list in the [Help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx), I see no method for writing individual bytes (and the Write methods seem to close the file after writing).

How can I write a byte array into a file, keep it open and repeat this as necessary?

(I am using Visual Studio 2005, if it's relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `FileStream`:

```
Dim file As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName)
```

You use the `Write` method to write a byte array (or part of it) to the stream:

```
file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```

The `Write` method doesn't close the stream, you can write as many times you like.

When you have written what you want, you use the `Close` method to close the stream:

```
file.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Guffa, Don't I know you from somewhere? ;-) -- According to the documentation (the page I linked to in the question), the File class does not have a Write() method. So, where does this come from?

Comment: @ysap: The `File` class is just a static class that contains some useful static methods, but it doesn't represent an opened file. The `FileStream` class is what you use to handle an opened file, and it's that class that has the `Write` method.

Comment: I need to separate the `OpenWrite` operation from the `Dim` declaration, i.e., the `file` variable should be a member of the class and not a local variable. This is b/c I am opening, writing and closing in all different methods. So, I played a little with the code, but I get an error for every combination I try. Last time I programed in VB was years ago on VB6, so even I can implement this in the "old style", I am trying to make it compatible with the .NET spirit.

Comment: OK, problem solved. I defined `file` as `FileStream` without the assignment in the members area, then used `file = File.OpenWrite(name,mode)` in the Open method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [**`BinaryWriter` class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx), also in the `System.IO` namespace.

The various overloads of the [`Write` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx25z45h.aspx) allow you to write values to the file, and then advance the current position in the stream by the appropriate number of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BinaryWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method:

```
BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"C:\Test.txt", FileMode.Create)))

byte[] byteValue = // set the value here ..
binWriter.Write(byteValue );
```

---

Refer to:

[BinaryWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)

Comment: thanks. Did you mean that the first keyword should be `Dim` and not `BinaryWriter`? Otherwise, I get an error.

Comment: Don't forget to binWriter.Close() after finishing the write.